# How to disable ESLint in vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

How do I go about disabling `ESlint` in project generated with `vue-cli`?

```
preLoaders: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'eslint',
    include: projectRoot,
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'eslint',
    include: projectRoot,
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
]
```

If I remove the `loader: 'eslint'` line it won't compile, same with setting it to an empty string. I know I can opt out of `ESLint` during the initialization phase, but how can I disable it after my project has been created?

Comment: Which template are you using? Simple webpack?

Comment: full-featured Webpack

Comment: Look at the `{{#lint}}` blocks in https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/cbcba9268dbfb277497bcdde6409dab4398eed8e/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js - can probably drop the entire `preLoaders` block?

Comment: @HectorLorenzo Moved it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vue's starter projects are themselves built with a templating language.

Looking at [the templates](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/cbcba9268dbfb277497bcdde6409dab4398eed8e/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js) (the `{{#lint}}` bits) it appears you can remove the entire `preLoaders` block.

Comment: Also, a cheap fix in case OP wants to easily enable and disable it is to add paths to the .eslintignore file.

Comment: `src/*.js` didn't help to disable eslint for src file ... may be needed to take some extra steps? @BillCriswell

Comment: Yup. Blocking out [this part](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L33-L41) works.

Comment: @Asqan you might want to use ```src/**/*.js``` and ```src/**/*.vue``` to ignore files recursively

Comment: I'm assuming this is how to disable before using the "vue create..." command?  How do we disable eslint after creating a project?

Answer (score 159):

There are some out-of-date answers here.

Because vue-cli 3 is using a zero configuration approach, the way to disable it is to just uninstall the module:

```
npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint
```

Comment: Since the original question is 3 years old, this should definitely be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: This is only correct if you want to fully remove linting. If you just want to removing linting "ON SAVE" then use the solution provided by Aakass hand Radbyx.

Comment: Solution works and prevents from unnecessary stress

Comment: I removed `@vue/cli-plugin-eslint` and now the command `vue-cli-service serve` says `Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-eslint'`. What else is needed?

Answer (score 124):

## As of `2019, March` :

In the `vue.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  lintOnSave: false
  ...
}
```

Comment: This works well if you want your IDE to handle linting based on .eslintrc.js, but have linting disabled when using the dev or watch npm-scripts.

Comment: npm remove is better. https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages says
This value is respected only when @vue/cli-plugin-eslint is installed.

Comment: Despite the name, this setting really does disable lintOnBuild. Unlike other answer of uninstalling the cli plugin, this answer lets you still use the `vue-cli-service lint` command when you want it.

Answer (score 59):

in `package.json` change the build step:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint",
    ...
},
```

Comment: This works! Answers prior to 2020 want you to add configs to files that no longer are part of the vue-cli template.

Comment: This works great, just note that if you pass in other arguments, you'll need to do this first. Example: vue-cli-service --skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint electron:build

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am back to work and can finally focus on programming instead of removing helpful spaces and empty lines  :)

Comment: As of end of 2022: I wanted to run `npm run serve`, not `build`. Adding `--skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint` to `"scripts": { "serve: vue-cli-service serve }"` property in package.json worked. I'm using vue=3.2.13, @vue/cli-service=5.0.0

Answer (score 35):

As of the current version (^3.0?) you can just set:

```
useEslint: false,
```

in `config/index.js`

Comment: you will need to do `npm run dev` again after doing changes to config

Comment: This didn't work for me, and this option is no longer documented in the vue cli docs.  What did work for me was simply deleting the `@vue/cli-plugin-eslint` module from my project

Answer (score 10):

In the latest version, open the ".eslintrc.js" file, and set "root: false".[image]

Comment: Of course it's not working since `root` only tells ESLint that all the rules from parent folder should be dismissed.

Comment: you can comment parser property in parserOptions

Answer (score 7):

There's a hell lot of solutions here:
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/73

However the best one is : 
To add a line of `**/*` to .eslintignore, which will ignore all files.
And then re-run, if it's a web app!

Answer (score 6):

One of the most simple way is just setting an `.eslintignore` file with you want to disabled folders & files.

> demo

```
/build/
/config/
/dist/
/*.js
/test/unit/coverage/

/000-xyz/
```

Ref: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/73#issuecomment-355149342

Answer (score 5):

For Vue cli v4 and project created with eslint feature selected, there's a `eslintConfig` property in package.json:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
```

[`extends`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#extending-configuration-files) specifies some rule presets and default is `plugin:vue/vue3-essential` and `eslint:recommended`. Common rules like unused variables or unused imports are in `eslint:recommended`. **If you want to disable such rules, just remove `eslint:recommended` in `eslintConfig` and restart the project, but don't remove `plugin:vue/vue3-essential` otherwise linter will not be able to recognise `.vue` files.**

Answer (score 4):

At first you need to create a file name of

> vue.config.js

then write bellow line

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  lintOnSave: false
  ...
}
```

This process worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To disable Eslint for **one line** you can put a comment above the line you want to disable Eslint check.

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

To disable Eslint for the **whole file** you can write a comment below on top of the file.

```js
/* eslint-disable */
```

To disable Eslint for **one specific file or folder** you can include it to `.eslintignore`.

***.eslintignore***

```
/src/components
```

Same way if you want to disable Eslint in the **entire project** just set the path below.

***.eslintignore***

```
**/*
```

To disable some **specific rule check** you can "off" it in `.eslintrc.js`.

***.eslintrc.js***

```js
module.exports = {
 rules: {
    "no-console": "off",
 },
}
```

`no-console` rule will disable warnings when using console.log, you can find all available rules in [Eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/) and [Vue Esint plugin](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/) docs.

Answer (score 3):

Go inside file "tslint.json" and exclude all files in linterOptions. Default settings only excludes folder node_modules. You may also set "strict": false, inside tsconfig.json

```
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "*/**"
    ]
  },
```

instead of

```
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

`setEslint: false` work for me!

```
module.exports = {
  dev: {
     ...
    // Use Eslint Loader?
    // If true, your code will be linted during bundling and
    // linting errors and warnings will be shown in the console.
    useEslint: false,
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: no, that stops eslint running in webstorm — I don't get red squiggles.

Comment: `setEslint` or `useEslint`?

Comment: Works great for me! I do not want to remove eslint, just to shut it up while I do dev work.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `.eslintrc.js` and add this:

```js
dev: {
   useEslint: false
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either delete it using the command

```
npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint
```

Or Disable it for a particular file by using the below command in that file's script tag

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

Answer (score 1):

Set 
`useEslint: false,` in `config/index.js`

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZpyA.png)

Comment: Add some description

Answer (score 1):

to easily to this just uninstall using the following commands

```
npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint
yarn remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint
```

Answer (score 1):

I personaly in order to get over that problem, created a new project and manually emited the Linter / Formatter option from the setup

i dont solve the problem i just try avoid it.
Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

For vue3 users, just comment out the parserOptions in the eslintrc.js file. it works for me cos sometimes linting can become frustrating

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  // parserOptions: {
  //   parser: 'babel-eslint'
  // },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in vueCli go to package json remove eslint from dependencies at end your package json must like this

```js
{
  "name": "vuecompesation",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0"
  
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.eslintignore`, add

```
/*/
```

Lint will no longer complain

Answer (score -1):

This should work

in **vue.config.js** add this

```
module.exports = {
    lintOnSave: false
}
```