# How to complete remove eslint in vue cli 3 generated project?

Tags: vue.js

I am not interested in the stupid lint, which is not workable at all. It can do nothing but waste of my time.

I need a way to remove it and make sure ESLint will never appear again. What should I do? Please don't tell me to put a comment in my code to disable one warning. I need a solution to completely get rid of ESLint in vue cli 3 generated project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable ESLint in vue-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757069/how-to-disable-eslint-in-vue-cli)

Answer (score 12):

1. Remove all references to eslint in package.json (`"@vue/eslint-config-x"` and `"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint"`)
2. Remove .eslintrc or eslintconfig in your project root dir
3. run `npm i`

Comment: After doing those steps my NUXT js project not running anymore. error code ELIFECYCLE.

Answer (score 0):

If Vue generated a config file for your project, you can look inside the `config\index.js` file and change useEslint to be false, as such: 
`useEslint: false`

Answer (score 0):

setting     `useEslint: false,`  in

> config/index.js

did the trick for me