# How to add eslint to an existing vue-cli project?

Tags: vue.js, command-line-interface, eslint, vue-cli

I created `vue cli` project without `eslint` option.
But now I want to try to test it.
How to add `ESLint` in existing `vue cli` project?

Comment: Stack exchange is not the place for `how to?` Please specify any issues or errors that you get while addressing your problem.

Comment: please , write on business

Comment: Pointing what's considered best practice and what should be avoided at SO *is* on business. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Your question lacks research efforts, hence is not that well recieved. You also haven't shown your setup so it's harder not to wild-guess to answer. Perhaps this Q&A may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38757069/3995261 but you haven't specified if you use webpack, what your config/index.js looks like etc. You haven't even shown the line you used to create the project to make your issue reproducible. Doing so will increase chanses of getting

Comment: a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just execute `npm i --save @vue/cli-plugin-eslint`

Docs can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, i found description here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/plugins-and-presets.html#installing-plugins-in-an-existing-project