# Vue - Disable Eslint

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-cli-3, vetur

I did some research, but could not find a quick fix to this situation:

[image: eslint]

```
Vue-cli 3.4.0 - Webpack 4.29.0
```

- My project does not have `config/index.js` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712327/7311199).
- I tried to open vue.config.js and disable eslint does not work.
- I removed the `cli-plugin-eslint` package.
- Don't have `.eslintrc.js`.
- Could not find any other configuration about eslint in project.

> **--- Fix ---**

I realize that I didn't control my settings well. It was built in ***vetur***.

[image: disable vetur eslint]

Comment: Is it built in to your editor?

Answer (score 5):

the easiest way to ignore eslint is to ignore the files you dont want to be linted. For example, create `.eslintignore` in your project root folder. then just add the following folder which you dont want to lint like,
add `src\`