# How can I disable eslint correct?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, eslint

I had follow the reference : https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories, but it does not work

I want to disable it, because I have many warning when run `npm run serve` about extra semicolon, spaces etc

My project using vuetify

[image]

I make .eslintignore and add script like this :

```
../src/*.js
```

I try to run `npm run serve`, but the warning is still exist

I try to add :

`"eslintIgnore": ["store.js", "Home.vue"]` in the `package.json`, but it also does not work

Whereas I had follow the docs

How can I solve this problem?

**Update** :

I try change like this :

```
src/**/*.js
src/**/*.vue
```

It does not work

Comment: Why bother with ESLint at all if you want to ignore your entire `src` directory? In any case, try `src/**/*.js` and `src/**/*.vue` in your `.eslintignore` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable ESLint in vue-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757069/how-to-disable-eslint-in-vue-cli)

Comment: @Phil Becuase there are many warning when run `npm run serve`. So I want to disable it. Your way is not work

Comment: @Phil Before make this question, I had search reference(including the link above), But it does not works. that's why I made this question

Comment: Either write your code to adhere to the ESLint rules or disable / remove ESLint entirely. Your question still shows `../src/*.js` which will not work. If you've tried something else, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58634424/edit)

Comment: The linked duplicate also shows several methods for disabling and removing ESLint. Have you tried all of those?

Comment: @Phil I had update my question. I had tried all of those. but it does not work

Comment: What is `src/**/*.` meant to match? It won't match any `.vue` files which is why my first comment above has `src/**/*.vue`

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry. I had update it

Comment: So you've updated `.eslintignore` and restarted your server, yes? What warnings **exactly** are you seeing?

Answer (score 27):

**Eslint lint is a javascript opensource for linting utility. When you install a project using Vue cli, it automatically adds eslint-plugin to your project. It will have a es6 syntaxes guidelines, You can also create or disable the eslint rules.**

> If you want to disable eslint for a single line

just append this to a line of code

```
javascript code // eslint-disable-line
```

> If you want to disable eslint for a complete file

```
/* eslint-disable */

code
/* eslint-disable */
```

> If you want to remove eslint completely from a project which is
>   created by vue cli 2

Set useEslint: false, in config/index.js

> If you are using vue cli 3

In .eslintrc.js just set

root: false

> Else, if you want to remove eslint completely  from project

npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint

> If you have .eslintignore, you can add these lines there

```
/build/
/config/
/dist/
/*.js
/test/unit/coverage/

/000-xyz/
```